# Does spring data save iterable method uses batch operation and return results in same order?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a list of entities that I need to persist using spring data. Some of them already have ids and some of them doesn't. After reading other similar questions I realized that repository method `save(Iterable<S> iterable)` uses ArrayList internally, so result is always in the same order. But the thing that made me nervous was the fact that it uses for each loop in it's implementation and saves entities one by one:

```
@Transactional
    public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {
        List<S> result = new ArrayList();
        if (entities == null) {
            return result;
        } else {
            Iterator var3 = entities.iterator();

            while(var3.hasNext()) {
                S entity = var3.next();
                result.add(this.save(entity));
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Due to specialties of my task I absolutely NEED to have results in the same order, My actual task is DB requests optimization, and I always assumed that when I pass collection to the save method it uses batch operations with hibernate, but now I'm wondering if this is actually true.

In case it isn't, is it even possible to perform BATCH insert/update operation with spring data and get results entities in the same order that I passed then in, or am I just imagining things?

Comment: If you haven't configured batches in Hibernate it will not batch anything. Also the order in which the SQL is executed has nothing to do with the order in which things are returned. That being said, relying on ordering in your code is a bad and brittle design imho.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the code the order of the elements is actually preserved. Although this is not strictly guaranteed for implementations of `CrudRepository.saveAll` methods it is unlikely to change, sind AFAIK there is no reason to change it.

As M.Deinum pointed out batching in Hibernate is completely unrelated to the order of save operations and depends on you configuration of Hibernate.

So yes: Batching is possible with Spring Data JPA.